# Swift UIWebView LoadRequest

Tags: swift, uiwebview

In order to load urls, I tried to connect .loadRequest with webview, but there is not such loadRequest. Is there anyone who knows why this is occurring to me?

```
func configurationView(){
    if let webData: Web = self.detailItem {
        if let webView = self.WebView {
            let url = NSURL(string: webData.url)
            let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            (here I am trying to dp WebView.loadRequest(urlRequest), but I cannot!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add more code. The description of your `WebView` object from this line: `if let webView = self.WebView`. Why you do this `if let webView = self.WebView` but then not use `webView` and what is `WebView` in your code? Is it `IBOutlet` ?

Comment: It isn't clear, but it looks like a typo so you're trying to call a class method that doesn't exist. Show the actual code and the compile error.

Comment: Thank you for your involvement in my problem, but I figured out a way to fix this issue! I just did not set UIWebView onto my source code. How stupid I am... Haha. Again, thank you so much!! :)